# Apply optim {stats} on merged datasets with different time granularities

Tags: r, optimization, merge, statistics

I already prepared the following data.frame:

```
> head(DF)
time       x        y
33.8351   NA 952.7843
40      1030       NA
40.11   1031       NA
40.22   1039       NA
40.32   1046       NA
40.43   1053       NA
```

Due to the `NA` values, `optim` gives me the following error:

```
Error in optim(par = c(0, 1), min.RSS, data = DF) : 
function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
```

So what should I do here? Create a dataset with rounded values to get a minimum number of filled rows and drop the rest? I'm clueless.

EDIT: I'm trying to minimize the residual sum of squares of my data against a linear model with two parameters.

```
  min.RSS <- function(data, par) {
              with(data, sum((par[1] + par[2] * x - y)^2))
  }
```

Imagine the problem like this: There is a dataset A with a limited number of data points and a curve (much larger set B of data points). The aim is to rescale the curve such that it agrees optimally with the dataset A. The rescaling is the linear model and I try to optimize the slope and the y-intercept of linear equation.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? Is the min.RSS self defined function?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't include the function. Updated.

Comment: Is it essential to keep NA in your data frame? can you remove rows that contain NA fields?

Comment: Then I have no rows left, due to the different time granularities there are no two identical time points.

Comment: Then you probably need to preprocess your data before hand. Set up time windows and do average for x and y in each window and then apply the function to the new data frame.

Comment: That's what I thought. I hoped that besides such a degradation of the data there was some kind of rank correlation algorithm which doesn't need datasets of identical length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolate the data.  Here we use `DF` shown in the Note at the end.  Below we use `na.locf` from the zoo package.  Also see `na.approx` and `na.spline` from the same package for other interpolation schemes.

```
library(zoo)
lm(y ~ x, na.locf(DF))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = na.locf(DF))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
      952.8          0.0
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "time       x        y
33.8351   NA 952.7843
40      1030       NA
40.11   1031       NA
40.22   1039       NA
40.32   1046       NA
40.43   1053       NA"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```